# onEnter prop in react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I'm using `react-router v4`. I find it confusing that when I click on `<Link>` component, the route is immediately changed. I want to stay at the current route before I fetch the data, not to switch the route and then fetch the data. I find that in `react-router v3` there's a `onEnter` hook, but now in `react-router v4`, it is deprecated. So how can I fetch data right after I click on `<Link>` component and before the route is changed?

**Example:**

it's: at `A` -> click at `<Link> to B` -> fetching data for `B` -> render `B`

not: at `A` -> click at `<Link> to B` -> render `Route B` -> fetching data for `B` -> rerender `B`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `react-router v4`, you can make use of `render` prop to `Route` to replace the `onEnter` functionality existing in `react-router v3`

Suppose you have a route like in `react-router v3`

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} onEnter={getData} />
```

The Equivalent of this in `react-router v4` would be

```
<Route exact path="/" render= {() => {getData(); return <Home data={this.state.data}/>}} />
```

However the suggested method is to make use of `lifecycle` methods in the `component`.

From the **[Github discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3854#issuecomment-279410103)**:

> ```
> We have no lifecycle hooks that receive props on initial render.
> ```
>
> We no longer have a "route lifecycle". Instead, since `<Match>`
>   components are real components (not pseudo-components like s
>   were) they get to participate in React's lifecycle, which means they
>   can just use `componentWillMount`.

So one of the suggested solution is:

> v4 is all about routes just being components. That means taking advantage of
>    lifecycle methods.
>
> ```
> componentWillMount() { // or componentDidMount
>   fetch(this.props.match.params.id)
> }
>
> componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { // or componentDidUpdate
>   if (nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
>     fetch(nextProps.match.params.id)
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I didn't mean to replace onEnter. For example, in your code, getData() may take 1 second or more. However, <Home /> is returned before data gets back. So you are in { Home } and waiting for data. What I want to do is before you render <Home/>,  get the data, and then switch to { Home }.

Comment: @ONIAKI, unfortunately v4 doesn't have a functionality like that. There are a few approached given in the Github discussion. It is encouraged to make use of lifecycle hooks for fetching data

Comment: That's quiet confusing. I understand their philosophy but it blocks some ways to interact with users. Em... I've used vue.js and vue-router can do what exactly I say. Maybe I should consider switching to react-router v3 before I find a good solution.

Comment: Indeed it does but we need to find ways around it

Comment: I think I've found the correct way. Using history.push() can programmatically change the route, so I can fetch some data before route is changed.

Comment: Adding side effects (getData()) to your render is a really poor pattern and should be avoided. React lifecycle methods are definitely the way to go

Comment: @UlysseMizrahi I did mention the same in my answer.

Comment: yes but the way the answer is formulated makes it sound like the render method is the default way to do it, and the lifecycle method is just a "better" way to do it, when the lifecycle method is really the only decent answer. I would not mention the first solution at all, people may brush over your further lifecycle explanation and use that one.