# How to use onLeave and onEnter ( or some hacks ) in Route with react-router-dom 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

There is nothing in my console when I follow "localhost:3000"
Which hooks ( or something else ) I can use instead ?

```
export default function getRoutes(store) {

  return (
    <AppComponent>
      <Switch>
          <Route 
            exact
            path="/" 
            component={CatalogBasePageComponent}
            onEnter={() => console.log('Works fine')}
          />
          <Route 
            path="/products/:ratingFilter/:categoryId" 
            component={CategoryProductsByFilterPageComponent}
          />
          <Route 
            path="/products/:ratingFilter" 
            component={CategoryProductsByFilterPageComponent}
          />
          <Route path="/category/:categoryId" component={CategoryPageComponent} />
          <Route path="/404" component={NotFoundComponent} />
      </Switch>
    </AppComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions should help you

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page/45869459#45869459  for `onLeave` and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429963/fetching-data-before-route-change-in-react-router-v4/45430656#45430656 for `onEnter`