# Performing Authentication on Routes with react-router-v4

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, react-router

I'm trying to write `Authentication` checking for my `DashBoard`. But the function itself is not getting called. Can anyone give me some solution for this? I'm developing in ReactJs.

This is the Route part :

```
 <Router>
            <div>
              <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
              <Route path={"/SignUp"} component={SignUp} />
              <Route path={"/SignIn"} component={SignIn} />
              <Route path={"/Dashboard"} component={Dashboard} onEnter={this.requireAuth} />
            </div>
          </Router>
```

This is the function :

```
  requireAuth (nextState, replace) {
    console.log("?????????????",this.state.getToken);
    if(!this.state.getToken) {
      replace({pathname: '/'});
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you are using React-router v4, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429963/onenter-prop-in-react-router-v4/45430656#45430656

Comment: I've changed like :     " <Route path={"/Dashboard"} component={Dashboard} render= {() => {requireAuth(); return <Dashboard />}} />"     But I'm getting    "bundle.js:6004 Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route render> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored"      error.

Comment: as the error suggests you shouldn't be both component and render together, render the component Dashboard from the render prop as suggested in the answer on the link

Comment: <Route path={"/Dashboard"} render= {() => {requireAuth(); return <Dashboard />}} /> for this error is showing as "requireAuth is not defined"

Comment: wouldn't it be `this.requireAuth()`

Comment: I've tried with this.requireAuth() also. Same error is coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160403/discussion-between-riya-kapuria-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `react-router v4`, you can make use of `render prop` to `Route` along with the lifecycle methods to replace the `onEnter` functionality existing in react-router v3.

See this answer for more details:

[onEnter prop in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429963/onenter-prop-in-react-router-v4/45430656#45430656)

However since all you want to do is authentication in the onEnter prop, you could easily create a HOC that does that

```
const RequireAuth = (Component) => { 

    return class App extends Component { 
    
        componentWillMount() { 
            const getToken = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
            if(!getToken) { 
               this.props.history.replace({pathname: '/'}); 
            } 
        } 
        render() { 
           return <Component {...this.props} /> 
        }
    } 

} 

export { RequireAuth }
```

and use it like

```
<Route path={"/Dashboard"} component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)}/>
```

Edit: In case you need to make a network call to find if the use if authenticated of not, you would write the HOC like

```
 const RequireAuth = (Component) => { 

    return class App extends Component { 
        state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            isLoading: true
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            AuthCall().then(() => {
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false});
            }).catch(() => {
                this.setState({isLoading: false});
            })
        } 
        render() { 
           const { isAuthenticated, isLoading } = this.state;
           if(isLoading) {
               return <div>Loading...</div>
           }
           if(!isAuthenticated) {
               return <Redirect to="/login" />
           }
           return <Component {...this.props} /> 
        }
    } 

} 

export { RequireAuth }
```

**Update:**

In addition to the HOC, you can also go for the `PrivateRoute` component like

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthenticated, isLoading, ...rest }) => { 
           if(isLoading) {
               return <div>Loading...</div>
           }
           if(!isAuthenticated) {
               return <Redirect to="/login" />
           }
           return <Component {...this.props} /> 
        }
    } 
} 

 export { PrivateRoute };
```

and you can use it like

```
  class App extends Component { 
        state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            isLoading: true
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            AuthCall().then(() => {
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false});
            }).catch(() => {
                this.setState({isLoading: false});
            })
        } 
        render() { 
           <Router>
              <div>
                  <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
                  <Route path={"/SignUp"} component={SignUp} />
                  <Route path={"/SignIn"} component={SignIn} />
                  <PrivateRoute path={"/Dashboard"} component={Dashboard} isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} isLoading={this.isLoading}/>
               </div>
           </Router>
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could someone not just edit the react state via react dev tools to make `isAuthenticated: true` and `isLoading: false`? Then they would have access to the protected route

Comment: @JL9 if they do this they would get to the view, but if they send an invalid request to the backend the server should respond with 401 and the ui would then redirect to login