# React HOC to check for authorized user (protected routes)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, higher-order-components

I am trying to build a Higher Order Component that would be used to protect routes.It would check (via a network call, not from cache) for the current user, and if not found, would redirect to /login.

Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [performing-authentication-on-routes-with-react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627818/performing-authentication-on-routes-with-react-router-v4/47628941#47628941)

Answer (score 2):

First understand how [React HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) works. I'll try to answer this using  the pseudo code.

**HOC.jsx**

```
export default (Component) => class HOC extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      waiting: true,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.validateUser() // your network call to validate user
    .then(() => {
      // do your stuff
      this.setState({
        waiting: false,
      })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // handle redirect using react-router
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.waiting) {
      // Add a loader here
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>
    }

    return <Component {...this.props} />

  }

}
```

**Component.jsx**

```
import HOC from './HOC.jsx'

class Comp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>I'm a valid user</h1>
  }
}

export default HOC(Comp)
```

When any component uses the HOC, the network call will be executed on mount (can be moved to `componentWillMount` as well) and based on the response the component will be rendered.

Hope this helps!