# React Router | different component in same url

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

I'm using [React Router 4.2.0](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic). In my scenario I have to load different components in same url.

I have two components `Login` and `Dashboard`

when I run `localhost:3000` component should load based on the `localstorage` flag.

I tried with following code It shows 404 page

```
 <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
 <Route path="/" render={(props) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('user')) { 
       return <Dashboard /> 
    }
    else {
       return <Login />
    }
 }} />
```

Comment: Its always better to have separate route for login, you can redirect to that route if the person is not loggedIn, Check this answer on how to perform authentication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627818/performing-authentication-on-routes-with-react-router-v4/47628941#47628941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default routes are matched in an inclusive manner (as many as possible). The wildcard catches everything, if you need to switch between them in an exclusive manner, you need to use the `Switch` component. In others words:

```
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} exact/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
```

The above will match the login page on the root, then fallback on the 404.