# How to redirect to another route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

There is one need for url authentication:

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
...

const IndexRouter = ({ loggedIn }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/"
      render={() => (loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <Login />)}
    />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardRouter} />
    <Route exact path="/stock" component={StockRouter} />
  </Switch>
);

export default connect(
  state => ({
    loggedIn: state.persist.loggedIn
  }),
  {}
)(IndexRouter);
```

The code means if I have not logged in, all of url are required from client will redirect to `Login` component. Other than that it will route to `DashboardRouter`.
The `StockRouter` is another route related with `DashboardRouter`.

The problem is that if I logged in. All the unspecific url (except `/dashboard`, `/stock`) I manually typed showing the `/dashboard` url without anything. The specific url such as `/stock` can show the component `StockRouter` directly.

Comment: What do you mean by unspecific URL?

Comment: The url is not contained in my router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write a `PrivateRoute` wrapper around your Route and change the order of Routes in IndexRouter, so that the Route with path `/` is matched at the last otherwise all routes will match `/` first and will not render correctly

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, loggedIn, ...rest }) => { 
           if(!loggedIn) {
               return <Redirect to="/login" />
           }
           return <Route {...rest} component={Component}/> 
        }
    } 
} 

const IndexRouter = ({ loggedIn }) => (
  <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardRouter} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/stock" component={StockRouter} />
    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
  </Switch>
);
```

For more details, check [Performing Authentication on Routes with react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627818/performing-authentication-on-routes-with-react-router-v4/47628941#47628941)

Comment: There is a little bug in this solution, if the url redirect to `/dashboard`, the `<PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardRouter} />` can not be rendered.

Comment: Replace `<Redirect to="/dashboard" />` to `<PrivateRoute path="/" component={DashboardRouter} loggedIn={loggedIn} />` can ugly drop this problem, however it make me a few confusion now.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a history component like this :

```js
import React from "react";
import {withRouter} from "react-router";

let globalHistory = null;

class HistoryComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const {history} = this.props;
    globalHistory = history;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    globalHistory = nextProps.history;
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export const GlobalHistory = withRouter(HistoryComponent);

export default function gotoRoute(route) {
  return globalHistory.push(route);
}
```

And then import into your component:

```js
import gotoRoute from "../../history";

gotoRoute({
                        pathname: "/your_url_here",
                        state: {
                            id: this.state.id
                        }
                    });
```

And in index.js

```js
import {GlobalHistory} from "./history";

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter >
      <div>
        <GlobalHistory/>
        <App/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>

), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This is the first time I can see to use react-router in this way.

Comment: If you want to send a object with route, or want to use in component then you can use the same