# React Authentication using HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-hoc

The server sends a 401 response if the user is not authenticated and I was trying to check for authentication in the front end using a HOC as seen in [Performing Authentication on Routes with react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627818/performing-authentication-on-routes-with-react-router-v4/47628941#47628941).
However, I am getting an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined` in RequireAuth

RequireAuth.js

```
import {React} from 'react'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

const RequireAuth = (Component) => { 

    return class Apps extends React.Component { 
        state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            isLoading: true
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
            const url = '/getinfo'
            const json = await fetch(url, {method: 'GET'})
            if (json.status !== 401)    
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false})
            else
                console.log('not auth!')
        } 

        render() { 
           const { isAuthenticated, isLoading } = this.state;
           if(isLoading) {
               return <div>Loading...</div>
           }
           if(!isAuthenticated) {
               return <Redirect to="/" />
           }
           return <Component {...this.props} /> 
        }
    } 

} 

export { RequireAuth }
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './SignIn'
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar'
import LandingPage from './LandingPage'
import Profile from './Profile'
import Register from './Register'
import { RequireAuth } from './RequireAuth'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
            <NavigationBar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path = '/'
                component = {LandingPage}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/register'
                component = {Register}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/profile' 
                component = {RequireAuth(Profile)}
              />
              <Route path="*" component = {() => "404 NOT FOUND"}/>
            </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: On line three of `App.js` above you're having `App` extend `React.Component` but you haven't imported `React` into that file yet.  This might be why you're getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined`-- because `React` is undefined in this context?  Although I guess I would expect in this context that you'd get a `ReferenceError` not a `TypeError`.

Comment: I had not copied the import statements but that is not the issue. Updated the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of some possibilities:

**------- Moved this to top which eventually fixed OP's issue -------**

1. Try remove the curly braces at `{React}`,

```
import React from 'react';
```

**------- Moved this to top which eventually fixed OP's issue -------**

---

2. In RequireAuth.js, Try

```
const RequireAuth = ({ Component }) => {} // changed from Component to { Component }
```

In App.js, use Component start with capital letter

```
<Route exact path = '/' Component = {LandingPage}/>
```

---

3. Also, in `<Route path="*" component = {() => "404 NOT FOUND"}/>`, looks like you're not passing in a React component because the function is not returning a JSX (I can't test now so I'm not very sure, though).

try this instead:

```
() => <div>404 NOT FOUND</div>
```

or if it doesn't work, define a functional component externally and pass into the `Route`:

```
const NotFoundComponent = () => <div>404 NOT FOUND</div>
```

```
<Route path="*" component = {NotFoundComponent}/>
```

Comment: @xyz6675 sry, `component`, according to your code, small letter, updated my answer

Comment: I changed that and then I had to change the line ``` return <Component {...this.props} />``` but then was getting the same error

Comment: Yes you have to, or you can remain capital letter and use capital also in your route like `Component={LandingPage}`

Comment: Also, in `<Route path="*" component = {() => "404 NOT FOUND"}/>` you're not passing in a component, maybe that's one of the cause too

Comment: @xyz6675 updated my answer again, hope it helps you

Comment: Sorry, appreciate the effort but it still does not go through

Comment: @xyz6675 last suggestion, try remove the curly braces: `import React from 'react';`, just figured out this classical mistake, couldn't help if that doesn't work :P

Comment: Yes it worked, can't believe that tiny issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helps, I edited by answer for better reading for whom may have the same issue

Comment: What can I do if I need to pass another prop to requireAuth from App?

Comment: @xyz6675 `const RequireAuth = ({ Component, anotherProp }) => {}`

Comment: Is there any way I can send the status of Authenticated/Not Authenticated to NavigationBar so that I render conditionally there?

Comment: @xyz6675 Yes, but it's a little too out of scope of this question and it's hard to reply in the comment section. Maybe you can open a new question for that.

Comment: Made a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294873/how-to-use-isauthenticatedstatus-in-hoc-to-send-to-navigationbar-to-render-condi

Comment: @xyz6675 You'll need to loft your authentication state out of the local component state of the `RequireAuth` HOC in order to use it outside a "Route" component, or refactor/rewrite it in such a way that doesn't couple it to your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like this:

```
const RequireAuth = ({ component: Component }) => {}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. It says that the error is on line  ```return class Apps extends React.Component { ```

Comment: i didn't know how i missed the react import that was in curly braces but i guess @andus answer is correct